# python code that prints list of all possible strings that can be made by just one given string

Tags: python, python-3.x

what could be the code if I want to write ta python code that prints all possible strings that can be formed from a given string.
for example.
if my in put is -"AB"
it should return -["A","B","AB","BA"]
all values  of the list in output should be different.

Comment: `[''.join(j) for i in range(1, len('AB')+1) for j in itertools.permutations('AB', i)]` what you need is `nP1, nP2,nP3 ....nPn` if you are familiar with permutation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at itertools.combinations:

```
itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
```

> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input
> iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted
> order.

Comment: <itertools.combinations object at 0x000001F4C6B9F5E0>

Comment: it shows this as output  what does it mean?

Comment: @DIVYANSHU it returns a **itertools.combinations object**, which you have to convert into a list in order to get the desired output. You can simply do that by calling list() on the object.